# Laravel validation causing query exception on save models

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

My application has two database connection:

```
mysql_default_connection => default_database
mysql_custom_connection => custom_database
```

And i'm having some problems with Laravel `unique` validation.

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_custom_connection';

protected $table = 'aluno';

public $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:custom_database.aluno'
];
```

When i try to save a new model, the unique rules works but When retrive some model from `aluno` and try to save it like:

```
$aluno = Aluno::find(1);
$aluno->attribute = 'new value';
$aluno->save();
```

This log:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'default_database.aluno' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `aluno` where `email` = aluno3@email.com and `id` <> 50)
```

If i remove the `unique` rules from validation, work fine.

Particularly, i can't understand why querying in `Table 'default_database.aluno'` because this database isn't the model connection as above.

Can someone explain to me why this occurs?

My connection config

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql_default_connection' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'port'      => 3306,
        'database'  => 'default_database',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],

    'mysql_custom_connection' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'port'      => 3306,
        'database'  => 'custom_database',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],
];
'default' => 'mysql_default_connection',
```

Relevant part from aluno model

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_custom_connection';
protected $table = 'aluno';
public $rules = [
    'nome' => 'required|between:5, 45',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:custom_database.aluno|max:64'
];
```

This rules works on create new models

**SOLUTION**

I'm using OctoberCMS that implement Laravel and this issue is a OctoberCMS trouble and not Laravel, sorry. To make validations on the model, we need to use the October Validation trait that get the `$rules, $attributeNames and $customMessages` arrays to call `Validator::make()...`.

In this trait, October simply ignores the model connection on validation

```
    /**
 * Instantiates the validator used by the validation process, depending if the class is being used inside or
 * outside of Laravel.
 * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
 */
protected static function makeValidator($data, $rules, $customMessages, $attributeNames)
{
    return Validator::make($data, $rules, $customMessages, $attributeNames);
}
```

And

```
  /*
  * Hand over to the validator
  */
  $validator = self::makeValidator($data, $rules, $customMessages, $attributeNames);
```

So, i do needed changes

```
 protected static function makeValidator($data, $rules, $customMessages, $attributeNames,$connection = null)
 {
     $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $customMessages, $attributeNames);
     if($connection !== null) {
         $validator->getPresenceVerifier()->setConnection($connection);
     }
     return $validator;
 }
```

And

```
 $validator = self::makeValidator($data, $rules, $customMessages, $attributeNames,$this->connection);
```

Now works like a charm

```
$rules = [
  'email' => 'required|unique:aluno'
];
```

Comment: Please show config. First check if you provided custom connection corectly in config. Try
$aluno = new Aluno;
$aluno->setConnection('custom');
$aluno->find(1);

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius but my connection is already setted on the model attribute $connection and work fine, the problem is when i use unique rule

Comment: Please show how you're doing the validation. Its trough model or requests ?

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius model

Comment: i've posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

just remove default_database from your validation, try this

```
public $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:aluno'
];
```

or try this if you want to specify the custom connection

```
public $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:mysql_custom_connection.aluno'
];
```

Comment: Laravel documentation says: "As seen above, setting unique:users as a validation rule will use the default database connection to query the database. To override this, specify the connection followed by the table name using "dot" syntax"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $rules = [
          'email' => 'unique:mysql_custom_connection.aluno,email'
     ];
```

It works, i've tried now. Just understand that aluno is table, you need to check unique FIELD not table.

Comment: for me: `Table 'mysql_custom_connection.aluno' doesn't exists`. Apparently there is using first argument as database name instead an connection of application

Comment: using: `database_name.aluno` works on creating new models but when update i have the exception

Comment: I see you dont understand. you cant define database name. What you are calling database is TABLE and second parameters is field (you are checking unique field not database.table. Please post database config (change credentials), model where you are doing validation and table structure if you want to get some help

Comment: dude, i know this. but why i need set 'email' field when the column name already is 'email'? not make sense

Comment: i solve this problem. i will edit my question with the solution, wait